# git cherry-pick does not work

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I get a strange error:

`git cherry-pick a0cd8fe`

`fatal: bad revision 'a0cd8fe'`

Why is that?

Note that the branch that `a0cd8fe` was merged to has been deleted. Is that why I get this error?

Comment: It sounds like this commit was garbage collected. What do you get with `git log a0cd8fe`?

Comment: fatal: bad object xxxxx....xxxxx

actually, i get this on any commits. why is that?

Comment: By `xxxxx` I assume you mean some SHA hash. What if you just do `git log`? What does that give?

Comment: Yes xxx is some SHA hash.

Comment: `git log` shows all the commits on the branch i am currently on

Comment: I feel git does not recognize this commit since the branch the commit was merged to has been deleted. It was deleted more than a month ago.
Is that plausible?

Comment: What happens if you use a SHA from one of the commits of your current branch with `git log`?

Comment: If you want to keep loose objects in a repo around for longer than the default 2 weeks, you can set the config variable `gc.pruneExpire`. E.g. `git config --local gc.pruneExpire 5.weeks.ago`. This way, git would wait 5 weeks before garbage collecting the loose commit objects.

Comment: You should note that @Alderath's suggestion will prevent this problem from occurring in the future. It will not restore the lost commit that you are currently asking about.

Answer (score 7):

That is because you don't have the remote branch (from where you want to cherry-pick) locally

**Solution**

```
git fetch origin <remote_branch>
git cherry-pick <commit_id>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just deleting a branch does not remove any commits. Immediately afterwards, any git command will work when given the SHA hash of a commit that was on the deleted branch. These so-called orphaned commits are eventually garbage collected after a set amount of time. From your output, it assists that this is what has happened. After garbage collection, the commit is permanently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same exact problem.

I resolved it by typing `git fetch` before `git cherry-pick xxxxxx`